# Will switching my driver to my installed memory make my watching streams smoother

Tags: disk-space, disk-management

I have an Acer aspire x3810 that has 2% free space in ACER(c:),(3.32GB), and has 87% free
space in DATA(D:).122.55GB. Will moving files and programs to this other storage help my gaming and watching experience smoother? I have an ATI Radeon hd 5500 video driver. I understand this is not top of line computer, but I feel I should have smoother video 
response

Answer (score 2):

> Will switching my driver to my installed memory make my CPU faster

The title does not make any sense.

I suspect you are confusing memory (temporary storage in RAM) and permanent storage on disk. Regardless of that: No, this will not make your CPU (which is a single chip in your desktop) any faster.

In the case that you are also confusing your CPU with the desktop: Probably not, though windows usually gets slower when free space on %%systemdrive%% (usually C:) drop to a few hundred MB.